# Import on shared object fails with ModuleNotFound only when script is executed from command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

ran into a weird problem where there is a shared-object import error only when I run the script from command line. It succeed if i run the script in the python console using exec(...)

I have a class that needs a shared object: foo.py:

```
import os
cur_dir = os.curdir()
os.chdir('/tmp/dir_with_shared_object/')
import shared_object_class
os.chdir(cur_dir)

class Useful:
    ... # use the shared object import
```

Then there is a script like this:

```
from foo import Useful
```

If I enter python console and run:

> exec(open('script.py').read())

Everything works fine.

If I run this on command line:

> python script.py

I will get

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shared_object_class'

The python is the same. It is 3.7.3, GCC 7.3.0 Anaconda. Anyone knows what is causing this discrepancy in behavior for shared object import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard way of importing from a custom directory would be to include it in the PYTHONPATH environmental variable, with `export PYTHONPATH=/tmp/dir_with_shared_object/`.

**update**
It could also be done dynamically with

```py
import sys
p = '/tmp/dir_with_shared_object/'
sys.path.insert(0, p)
```

**PS**

I think I have an explanation for why OP's original code didn't work. According to [this python reference page](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path), the import system searches, inter alia, in "[t]he directory containing the input script (or the current directory when no file is specified)." So the behavior in the REPL loop is different from how it is when running a script. Apparently the current directory is evaluated each time an import statement is encountered, while the directory containing the input script doesn't change.

Comment: The location of the shared object is not static, so I cannot set the python path before the script is called. But altering pythonpath within python does not enable it to pick up the shared object

Comment: Posted an alternative :)

Comment: I will be damned, but adding to the sys path works (even though the python path did not).  I thought I tried it alreayd. I will upvote this, since it works, but i will not mark as the answer, because the question is really trying to figure out the inconsistent behavior between the 2 different ways of running the script

Comment: Posted an explanation. Leaning new things myself. Python is really easy to get started, but it's just as quirky as any other computer language under the hood.